# TaeRichEditComponent60 - "открутить проверку принтера"

Tags: c++builder, c++

Есть замечательный компонент для С++ Builder 6.0 TaeRichEditComponent60.

Позволяет вставлять картинки в фаилы *.rtf. Но есть один недостаток: как и при запуске скомпилированного фаила на др. компе, так и при установке компонента в С++ Builder
требует наличие принтера. Вопрос: кто нибудь может "открутить" это дело от компонента?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, проще всего установить в систему виртуальный принтер, не меняя сам компонент.